How to separate retires in Allure Reports to separate tests?
In my project while triggering a test to run, we pass through variables as system properties e.g.:
public static String USER = System.getProperty("user", "ADMIN_HQ");

This is so we can run the tests with whatever user/browser/server etc. we need in that moment.
As this is a public string, it is called in the code when it is needed. Therefore there are no parameters passed through to the test method.
The issue I am having is how Allure reports display this. For example I may have a bash file run:
#!/bin/bash
mvn -Dtest=ScreenshotComparisonTests#salesForecastComparison -Duser=ADMIN_1 -Dbrowser=CHROME_HEADLESS test
mvn -Dtest=ScreenshotComparisonTests#salesForecastComparison -Duser=ADMIN_2 -Dbrowser=CHROME_HEADLESS test
allure serve target/allure-results

I want to see these listed as two separate test cases in the Allure Report but it groups them into retries. The issue with this is if the test fails for ADMIN_1 I won't see this if ADMIN_2 passes, unless I drill into the Retries tab for all tests. It makes the graphs and overall results useless. It also means I can't group the tests the way I would like e.g. a Story for each username etc
How can I separate these retries out into unique test cases?
I have tried assigning Epics, Stories, Features, parentSuite, Suite, subsuite etc.
I have also set Allure parameters for BeforeEach test is run:
        //Add Allure parameters
        Allure.parameter("Browser", browserVersion);
        Allure.parameter("OS Info", osInfo);
        Allure.parameter("Server", serverName);
        Allure.parameter("Build Version", version);
        Allure.parameter("Logged in as", USER);
        Allure.parameter("Machine username", machineUsername);

These parameters are different every time (in this example, Logged in as shows as ADMIN_2 on the test but shows as ADMIN_1 when I drill into the retries) but it still groups them as one test case.
I've tried looking at the container.json and result.json files to see could I figure out what needs to be changed here to have the report see them as separate test cases but I couldn't figure it out

Allure uses test results parameters to separate tests and retries. You must move the Allure.parameter calls from the setup method to the test body.
If all the parameters data available as system properties, you may consider using Allure Lifecycle Listener API to add parameters to all test cases automatically:
import io.qameta.allure.listener.TestLifecycleListener;
import io.qameta.allure.model.TestResult;
import io.qameta.allure.util.ResultsUtils;

import java.util.Objects;

public class ParametersListener implements TestLifecycleListener {

    @Override
    public void afterTestStart(final TestResult result) {
        final String user = System.getProperty("user");
        if (Objects.nonNull(user)) {
            result.getParameters().add(
                    ResultsUtils.createParameter(
                            "Username",
                            user
                    )
            );
        }
    }
}

Note: TestLifecycleListener need to be registered via SPI
